# Have two different click events on single div

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have to execute a div like this. When the user clicks on the `card`, it will be redirected to a different page, but when the user clicks on the `button` inside the `card`, it will be redirected to another page.

```
     <v-ons-card
      @click="goToPage1()"
    >
      <div>
        // content
      </div>

      <div class="card-btn">
        <v-ons-button
          @click="gotopage2()"
        >
          View
        </v-ons-button>
      </div>
    </v-ons-card>
```

In this implementation, when I click the button, it also triggers the card click event and then triggers the button click event. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [Event Modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) for that. In your case you are searching for `@click.stop`.

So you can do as follow:

```
<v-ons-button @click.stop="gotopage2()">
```